# Panel does not resize controls while creating control image

Tags: wpf, user-controls, stackpanel

I need to create an image of a custom WPF control and save it to file. I do it by this way (http://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/2007/12/03/wpf-diagramming-saving-you-canvas-to-image-xps-document-or-raw-xaml/).

The control contains several panels (ie. `StackPanel`). When this control is rendered on the form it looks perfectly. But when I render it in memory and save to file all controls in panels are not aligned. They take area that they need only and they doesn't stretch.

When I used WPF 3.5 it worked. This issue appeared after I updated my project to WPF 4.0.

Could anybody explain me what changes in WPF 4.0 cause this behaviour and how I can resolve it?